# Python urllib2 fails to open web page

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a problem where a page that I can open in Firefox, Chrome, or even Java fails to open in Python using urllib2:

```
import urllib2
sock = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
li = sock.read()
sock.close()
print li
```

This code fails (for the particular company web page I am trying to load). The page is actually an interface to a complex back-end server, and the response we are getting is just a couple lines of (incorrect) text. At first we thought there was some bot filtering going on, but we did get the page to load using Java:

```
package com.ebay.marketing.rtm.components.impl.selector;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class RtmApiCheck {

    private static Client mClient;

    private void initClient() {
        Client client = mClient;
        if (client == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                client = mClient;
                if (client == null) {
                    mClient = client = Client.create();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RtmApiCheck check = new RtmApiCheck();
        try {
            check.initClient();
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                WebResource wr = mClient.resource("http://www.example.com");
                ClientResponse result = wr.get(ClientResponse.class);
                String strResult = result.getEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println(strResult);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on with Python that causes this code to fail? Is there an alternative way to load the page that might work?

Comment: What was the response? What was expected?

Comment: Define "couple of lines of incorrect text". Do you get the expected HTTP response code, or are you getting a `400`/`500`? Is it just giving you random garbage? Is it only giving you part of the expected response? Without more details it's hard to help you, there's nothing inherently wrong with the code.

Comment: Having said that, you might want to look into using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, it's a much nicer way to interact with websites. The equivalent code would simply be `requests.get('http://example.com').text()`. For a simple parameterless `get` it's not a big difference, but for more complex operations you will thank yourself.

Comment: Are you able to post the actual URL, or is it internal / sekret?

Comment: I can't post the actual URL or text response, as it is secret. The HTTP response is 200. The text response isn't garbage, but it is useless: something on the server is failing to respond properly.

Comment: I did try the requests library, but that also failed in the same way.

Comment: @Madwand Does the server properly send headers? What happens id you try to send the same request with curl?

Comment: How do I test headers? Sorry, I'm pretty new to loading web pages in python. I tried pycurl, the test failed 8/10 times but succeeded twice. This is pretty much the same as the other tests too.